# Incorrect name keeps appearing in Mail.app account info

Tags: icloud, mail.app

I changed my name in iCloud a while ago, and then reverted that change. iCloud.com, the iCloud System Preference pane, and the info that appears in the Internet Accounts entry for the iCloud account are all correct. In Mail.app, it keeps sending emails as the previous name.

In ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Accounts.plist it shows the old name in Root -> MailAccounts -> Item 3 -> FullUserName, as well as both the EmailAlias entries. I can change these to the correct name in the plist and start Mail.app again, and it will revert these values back again.

I can't find anywhere where my previous name is specified.

Comment: Have recently setup iCloud on a new MBP and the incorrect name comes up there as well.

Comment: There are lots of separate places on iCloud.com where you set your account name, the important one for this is within the Mail Preferences itself. Is it correct there? http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177883/112471

Answer (score 1):

From http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/mitcontrib/Apple+Mail+shows+incorrect+name+for+email+address:

> #### Question(s)
>
> How come Apple Mail shows the wrong name when I type my email address in the To or CC field?
>
> #### Context
>
> AppleMail
>   Apple Mail
>   Mail.app
>   Address Book
>
> The name that shows up in the TO: or CC: field when typing an email address is incorrect.
>   (Ex. Joe User  instead of Joseph User )
>
> #### Solution
>
> Apple Mail pulls the name information from cards in the address book. If there is a card with the email address typed, it will try to use the name on that card. This can be changed by:
>
> - Open the address book
> - Search for the email address
> - Click Edit
> - Click the name in the card to change it.
> - Click Edit again to stop editing
>
> Test by trying to create a new message to the email address in question.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't find anything wrong for the given email in the address book. (contact.app)