How do I change the display name on iCloud email?
I'm using the Mail app on iOS 17.4.1, w/ an iCloud email address.
I do not want to change the email address associated with the Apple ID, only the display name on outbound emails.
For example, here is how my emails currently appear to somebody with a Gmail inbox:

John Brown <johnbrown@icloud.com>

The display name at the beginning is what I need to change, not the email address itself. I already updated my display name, under "Settings --> Apple ID --> Personal Information --> Name".
I've logged into "appleid.apple.com" and checked underneath "Personal Information --> Name", and already confirmed that it's updated there as well.
I've logged out of Mail and logged back in again.
No luck.
I understand this question has already been asked before, but the most recent answers to that question were posted in 2015, and are no longer applicable. Link.

Please give a link to the question that was answered in 2015.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177876/how-to-change-display-name-on-the-icloud-email

Did you see the 2022 answer? But, that doesn't seem to solve the question.

Yes, I saw and tried the 2022 answer. It didn't work unfortunately.

Please be sure to vote up this answer form 2016 and select yours as being the solution here. That helps everyone seeing either question know the proper answer. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230301/5472

I couldn’t get my device to pull down the new name, so my solution was to remove the corresponding iCloud account from the iPhone.
Adding it back brought down the changed name from the servers.
This process echoes another answer from 2016.
